# React UI doesn't update on redux store change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux State HOC to manage the connection

I Have a problem when I add a new post to the store

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

export default function withState(WrappedComponent) {
  function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    let state = {};
    for(let t of Object.entries(reduxState)) {
      state = {...state, ...t[1]}
    }
    
    return {
      ...state,
    };
  }

  return connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    null
  )(function (props) {

    useEffect(() => {}, [props.posts, props.comments]) /*tried this but didn't work*/
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <WrappedComponent {...props} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  });
}
```

I am trying to make the program render the response from my back-end without me reloading the page manually

I tried using the useEffect

and I saw through the dev tools that the state change correctly

my reducer

```js
import { GET_ALL_POSTS, CREATE_NEW_POST } from "../actions"

const initialState = {
    posts: []
}

export default function postReducer(state = initialState, action) {

    
    let newState = {...state}
    
    switch(action.type){
        case GET_ALL_POSTS:
            return {
                ...newState,
                posts: [...action.posts],
            }
        case CREATE_NEW_POST:
            const posts = [...newState.posts, action.post]
            return {
                ...newState,
                posts
            }
        default:
            return {
                ...newState,
            }
    }
}
```

I also read that react changes doesn't respond to shallow copies so I changed the whole array in the post reduces when I add a new post

Answer (score 0):

Your `withState` HOC is very strange.  I'm not sure why you don't just use `connect` directly (or use hooks).  But try this:

```
export function withState(WrappedComponent) {
  return connect(
    (state) => ({
      posts: state.postsReducer.posts,
      comments: state.commentsReducer.comments
    }),
    null
  )(WrappedComponent);
}
```

Comment: I have multiple reducers 

so my state looks like this : 
{
   postReducer:{...},
  commentReducer:{}
}

Comment: so I am just spreading the value to the global store

Comment: and the comments are totally irrelevant but I also need the UI to update with their changes

Comment: Yeah don't do that.  Just extract the values that you need.  You want your components to re-render only when there are changes in the pieces of state that they actually use.

Comment: What I am not getting is why is the store changing in the expected behaviour but the UI doesn't change

Comment: the thing is I am only keeping what I need in the store

Comment: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#connect-more-components-to-read-data-from-the-store

Comment: this is exactly how I am doing it

I have a Timeline component that grabs all the data and a post component that grabs from the store the exact entry that it needs

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your problem](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-davinci-gsgjs?file=/src/App.jsx)

Comment: do you mind if I share my screen with you by any means you like?

Comment: or if  u want u can just check the GitHub repo https://github.com/ahmedgaafer/blog-front-end

Comment: well, I went throw the CodeSandBox and I don't see any diff...

I am using redux-thunk and getting the data from an online DB but this shouldn't make a diff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230464/discussion-between-ahmed-gaafer-and-linda-paiste).